# How do I change this "schema" with out the need of transactions(ACID)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transactions, mongoose-schema

I have a model like the following one in MongoDB using Mongoose:

```
Stuff
{
_id: ObjectId...,
stuff: String..,
someBoolean: Boolean,
description: String,
transactionsOfThisStuff: [{
  trnsactionNumber: objectId?
  date: Date.now()
  info: String
 }]
}
```

As you can see, the idea is to move stuff, and I need to register every movement, so I made an array of "transactions" where I keep the history.

To make a "transaction" there are some requirements, for example, the "someBoolean" must be in certain value, etc.
And when a transaction is made, some values of the stuff must be updated.

Also, I must be able to move multiple stuff at the same time (move a table, a plumbus, etc), so all of them will have the same "transactionNumber" in each document.

The problem I see with this model is that I can't easily for example list the last 10 movements, or I don't find efficietn getting the Stuff that has been moved with a given "transactionNumber".

If a use two models:

```
Stuff
{
      _id: ObjectId...,
      stuff: String..,
      someBoolean: Boolean,
      description: String,
}

transaction
{
     _id: objectId,
     date: Date.now(),
     info: String,
     stuff: [{type:ObjectId, ref: 'Stuff', requiered: true}]
}
```

the problem with this idea, is that I would need ACID, since if move multiple Stuff, I need to update some values in the "Stuff" :/

Edit:

I save hardware parts, like CPU, Mouse, Keyboard, Monitor, etc. Each one of them is stored in "logical" warehouses. I can make different types of "transactions", like move it to another warehouse, give it to a person, take it back, etc. Each transaction must be tracked, so I can have a history of that item. Also, I can move many items at the same time within the same transaction, for example in the transaction number 21361764 I moved 10 different items. At the same time, I need to update some info in the item, like isStored: False, True.

The transaction itself must have the date of the execution, a client, a user (who is doing the transaction), and an array of items, etc.

The ideas above the edit are what I came so far, but each one has problems since I would need transactions. There must be a way to solve this problem without falling to a relational database.

Comment: Whilst there is likely a solution to your particular problem, the presentation of the question does not clearly describe what that problem is. Rather you should describe the process in the form of "actions" with "examples" of what happens and what rules need to be applied. Then it would be possible to make some determination of how to store and interact with the data based on how you actually use it. There simply isn't a sufficient demonstration of a use case here to apply a definitive answer. You need to make your use case your actual question.

Comment: @NeilLunn I made an edit, maybe that info can help to understand a little